# Multi-driver net found

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, error, vivado

I have been putting together a project for work in Vivado 2015.2 When I try and implement the design I get these errors. The project is pretty large that's why I haven't included it in the post. Is there a way to find this net error using the TCL command?

I can't find this `MEM/Q[0]` anywhere in the design.

> [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[0].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[10].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[11].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[12].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[13].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[1].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[2].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[3].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[4].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[5].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[6].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[7].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[8].
>   [Opt 31-37] Multi-driver net found in the design: MEM/Q[9].

Comment: Is there any module instantiated with the name "MEM"?

Comment: yes there is and I have been looking at the GIANT rtl schematic. but I can't find anything with Q. Not even sure what the Q[0] is??

Comment: Q is probably the internal name of a node inside the MEM module. Did you make two copies of something and call them both MEM?

Comment: no. MEM is the name of the memory_controller that I'm using for the internal block ram of the Artix-7 xilinx FPGA.

Comment: In your simulator, (at least in Modelsim and Isim) you can find all the drivers on a signal with the `drivers <signal_name>` command (or similar)

Comment: Multi driver net errors are most commonly caused by having two active drive outputs connected together, maybe two things going to one input.